# modifying response body and serve fragments

Tags: load-balancing, cdn, varnish-vcl, f5, fastly

We have a web app served via CDN, I want to turn it into a SPA/PWA and  need to serve the pages without the header footer (fragments only)

To achieve this, it will need to strip out some dynamic sections.. or pre-define points (`<!--strip-start-->`)

The question is: 
Does it make sense to post-process the response body via varnish or any other solution?

Should it be done on the load balancer (F5)?

Which library should be used?

How well does it scale?
What are the known issues?

Comment: Can't you do it from within the app?

Comment: Nope, I wouldn't try to do it this way if I could of do it in the app

Comment: If you have F5 already, stripping content from response payload is fairly trivial if you have clear markers.